# Loading .obj mesh with OpenGL ES and XCode

Tags: iphone

I created a .obj file from a 3d object that was made from Blender. I want want use the object in OpenGL ES using Xcode. Can anyone help me??

Comment: Well..... What have you tried?

Comment: How ta add export script to add .blend file to xcode?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) especially the section on "how to ask a question". You may want to then update your question to include all the relevant information of what you have tried and what, specifically, you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **NinevehGL** 3D engine.

**NinevehGL**  is a 3D engine forged with pure Obj-C

you can see the details [here](http://nineveh.gl)